# Can I set the permalink to the folder name in the Jekyll config file?

Tags: jekyll, permalinks

I know that variables are not allowed in the `_config.yml` file, but I want the functionality that

```
scope:
  path: "_pages"
values:
  layout: "interior"
  permalink: {{ page.url }}
```

would produce.

All of my pages are in their own folder so I don't want to have to repeat `permalink: {{ page.url }}` in the Front Matter of each page.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Try: "permalink: /:url" - but not tested!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a separate folder for (non-blog post) pages and that's what I was trying to set up the permalinks for. Turns out what I wanted was...

`permalink: /pagename/`

in my front matter.

Answer (score 0):

By "pages", do you mean posts? If that's the case, try:

```
scope:
  path: ""
  type: "posts"
values:
  layout: "Your layout"
  author: "Your name"
  permalink: /blog/:title/
```

and you can find out more about the permalink [here](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/).